# Read Excel and save into dictionary or List in .NET Core Test project C#?

Tags: c#, json, excel, .net-core

How can I Read Excel .xlsx/.xls and save into JSON File/dictionary or List  in .NET Core Console/Test project C#?
Oledb not supporting in .NET core.

Excel Data:

```
SerialNo   Code
1233534    3456
232443435  12101
565765     66690
```

Expected JSON :

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "serialNo": "1233534",
      "code": "3456"
    },
    {
      "serialNo": "232443435",
      "code": "12101"
    },
    {
      "serialNo": "565765",
      "code": "66690"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can use the Microsoft.office.interop.Excel Nuget package to read and write to excel files

Comment: If it's an option, use csv files instead of xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but...  If it helps any of the x... extensions in Microsoft Office, eg.  xlsx, docx etc are simply .ZIP files.  Change the extension to .zip and uncompress it.  You will see the structure of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example how you can do this dynamically.

Basically my example is a Console application that uses EPPlus library to read an excel file and gets from the first line of the first sheet the property names, then populates a list with objects and then it converts it to a Json using Newtonsoft library

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\test.xlsx";
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
    var properties = GetPropertiesFromExcelFirstLine(worksheet);
    var i = 2;
    var objectsList = new List<object>();
    while (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null && (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString() != ""))
    {
        objectsList.Add(GetObjectByLineNumber(worksheet, i, properties));
        i++;
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectsList);
}
static List<string> GetPropertiesFromExcelFirstLine(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var i = 1;
    while (worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value != null && (worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value?.ToString() != ""))
    {
        list.Add(worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value?.ToString());
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}

static ExpandoObject GetObjectByLineNumber(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int line, List<string> objectProperties)
{
    var obj = new ExpandoObject();

    for (int i = 1; i <= objectProperties.Count; i++)
    {
        AddProperty(obj, objectProperties[i - 1], worksheet.Cells[line, i].Value?.ToString());
    }

    return obj;
}

public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    else
        expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
}
```